# How to delete part of a class?

Tags: c++, oop

The problem is quite simple. I have a class that can be structured as the following:

```cpp
class MyClass {
  struct A {
    // ...
  };
  struct B {
    // ...
  };
};
```

The problem is: the information in `MyClass::B` is useless after some time of precomputations, whereas `MyClass::A` must never be deleted (the program may be running for days). `MyClass::B` holds quite a large amount of information. I want to get rid of `MyClass::B` while keeping `MyClass::A` in the same memory position.

Is it possible to do this without modifying too much the data structure and not having to add anything else to `MyClass::A` (in particular, a pointer to `MyClass::B`)? If so, what would be the right way to implement it? Take in account that the program must be as memory-efficient as possible (and let us take that to the extreme). I use C++14 BTW.

(And extra question: It is possible to delete the chunk corresponding to `MyClass::B` from `MyClass`?)

Comment: `MyClass::B` is a type. Types do not consume memory, variables do. But there are no variables in your example. Maybe you want `std::unique_ptr<B> b` as a data member instead of `B b`.

Comment: Factor out B and have a pointer to it

Comment: @Galik, I realized that and removed it from the comment. However, if `B` allocates on heap some fixed amount of storage, `std::optional` can be useful.

Comment: Why is it important to "keep `MyClass::A` in the same memory position"? Do you have an array of `MyClass` objects?

Comment: @Evg because I have pointers pointing to `A`

Comment: If a class uses some data only for *some time* they are not part of the class. It is not about "delete later", it is about OOP in general. Your problem sounds a bit weird. If you have "something" which computes and the result is something different, it is quite common to instantiate a new class later after that computation. But having all in one "god class" is bad design. You should read/think about "alias class", "factory pattern", "serializer". Some implementations are able to take alias classes, compute something and finally  create the needed objects while reading from a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's elaborate a bit on what I wrote: *“either the life of B is tied to that of MyClass, or it is independent. In that latter case, you must keep track of it in some way”*.

Putting the context back from the question:

- MyClass::B is useless after some time of precomputations.
- MyClass::A must never be deleted.

Is ensues that you want to keep track of it in some way. How? Well, that depends on the rules on the life time.

- If B could sometimes exist and sometimes not depending on hard to control (or plain unknowable) circumstances, then having a pointer to it, set to `nullptr` when it is useless, and dynamically allocated when it is useful is pretty much the only solution.

But here we have more knowledge: B exists first, then becomes useless and remains so forever. In other terms, you don't need B after some initial *building steps* used to create A.

There is a pattern that does exactly this: the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Its purpose is to encapsulate a complex building operation, maybe tracking some state, until it has built some object, at which point it becomes useless and can be destroyed.

```
class ABuilder
{
public:
    setSomeInfo(int);
    doSomeComputation(......);
    // etc

    A get();    /// finalize building of A

private:
    int someInfo_ = 0;
};

// somewhere else
auto b = ABuilder();
b.setSomeInfo(42);
b.doSomeComputation(......);

auto a = b.get();
// b is no longer used past that point
// delete it if it was allocated dynamically
// or let it go out of scope if it was automatic
```

From your example, it would map somewhat like this:

- `A` is still `A`.
- `B` is `ABuilder`.
- `MyClass` is not needed.

If you had provided actual class names and purpose, it would have been easier to make the examples meaningful ;)

Answer (score 7):

First or all that's a class declaration. You can't delete a part of the class declaration. You probably have something more like this:

```
// The exact place of the declaration doesn't matter actually
class A {...}; 
class B {...};

class C {
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

Just change it to use a pointer (in this day and age a smart pointer, like [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)):

```
class C {
    A a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;

    void FinishTaskThatRequiredB() {
        b.reset(); // calls B::~B() and frees the memory.
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @churill. However, that is what I'm trying to avoid (sorry, I was editing the post to clarify this while you were writing the answer). I want to work with `A` without having to deal with this extra pointer.

Comment: @VictorMartin, with `A` or with `B`?

Comment: @VictorMartin Why without a pointer? Any subobject (such as `b`) will occupy memory of an object as long as the latter exist. Sizes of objects are fixed in C++, so, the only option for you is to use a pointer.

Comment: Then what's the problem with having a pointer to `B`? A is unaffected by those changes.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica First, because I personally find it somewhat ugly and unnecessary, and second, ` the program must be as memory-efficient as possible` (and I want to take that to the extreme if possible)

Comment: @VictorMartin _because I personally find it somewhat ugly and unnecessary_ — Sorry, but this is a very wrong reason for not using something. Pointers are everywhere in C++ and you cannot avoid them when dealing with dynamic data. As for your problem, either the subobject of `B` will occupy its space all the lifetime of the corresponding `MyClass` object, or you will use pointers. You cannot have both.

Comment: Next best that comes to my mind would be a `std::map<A*, B>` (or possibly unordered). You could get rid of that entirely afterwards, but as long as initialisation is running, you'd need even more memory...

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I am just trying to find a better way if it exists?

Comment: @churill By the way, I don't see any reason why the nested classes should be moved out of C...

Comment: @VictorMartin Let's make it simple: either the life of B is tied to that of MyClass, or it is independent. In that latter case, you must keep track of it in some way.

Comment: @VictorMartin No, it does not. You simply cannot "delete" part of the object itself. `sizeof(MyClass)` is a constant value. Or course, there are other ways. For example, you can store the object of `B` outside of the object of `MyClass`, possibly on stack to avoid dynamic allocations.

Comment: @Aconcagua I found it easier to read, but already mentioned, that it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @VictorMartin If you _"want to take that to the extreme if possible"_ a pointer of 4 or 8 Byte is really too big, I guess and you would prefer borderline unreadable or unsave techniques?

Answer (score 0):

In any case, pointers are most likely the key to your desires. In any case, too, you *need* to separate `B` from `MyClass`, too. You can avoid a pointer within MyClass (see comments to question and other answer), if you store `B` separately and invert the direction of the pointer:

```
class MyClass
{
    struct A { };
    A a;
};

class Wrapper
{
    struct B { };

    MyClass* mc;
    B b;
};
```

Now during initialisation, you'd create a `Wrapper` for each `MyClass`, most likely contained in two different arrays:

```
MyClass items[NUMBER_OF_ITEMS]; // global array?

Wrapper* wrappers = new Wrapper[NUMBER_OF_ITEMS];
// assign each item to its corresponding wrapper

// use the wrappers for initialisation

delete[] wrappers;
```

Now all that remains is one single pointer, of which you even might get rid if it is a local variable in a separate initialisation routine...